# Hotel Booking System: optimal SQL db structure for querying

Tags: sql, design-patterns, database-design, software-design

I'm about to design a Hotel Booking system.

Each Hotel has some RoomTypes assigned.

`RoomType: id | name | hotel_id`

Each Hotel offers some quantities of RoomTypes for specific period (given `date_from` and `date_to`).
Also each Client has an ability to make a Reservation of some quantities of some RoomTypesfor specified period (`date_from` and `date_to`).

I need to be able to find & display available Offers for given Hotel, to know number of free (Offered - Booked) rooms of each RoomType for each day, query against minimum number of free rooms etc.

I'd like to ask for advice, **how should I keep the data**. What solution is optimal? I know some queries (like, display number of free rooms of given type for each day in given range) can't be achieved with simple SQL query unless I use stored procedures. However I'd like to make it as fast and easy to implement as possible.

so far I've considered:

1. keep `RoomOffer: hotel_id | date_from | date_to | quantity | room_type_id` and the same with Reservation
2. have `RoomOffer: hotel_id | date | quantity | room_type_id` and the same with Reservation - i.e. when creating RoomOffer / Reservation, create single record for every day in given range.

any advices?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `RoomType` refers to a single room, and also that the primary key for each room is the tuple `(hotel_id, room_type_id)`, since you use both fields for `RoomOffer`.

However, I do not recommend you to take the `RoomOffer` and `Reservation` approach. First of all, because you are storing a lot of redundant information: When a room is not still booked, you need a room offer to say that it is available (or even worse, plenty of them because you divide it by time ranges), something that you already know.

Instead of that, I'd suggest a desing more similar to this one:

[image: Booking System UML]

From your question I know you are concerned about the performance of the system, but usually **this kind of optimizations in the design phase are not a good idea**. Doing so probably leads you to a lot of redundant data and coupled classes. However, you can improve the performance of the DB queries using indices, or even with no-SQL approaches. That is something you can evaluate better in a later phase of the project.